# How do I change the TTS voice for action on Google Home?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

After building an agent for Google home, how do I change its voice? 
I remember there are 4 different voices, but can't find where to set it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The voice for your action is configured in the Actions Console. In the console, edit your app's information and change the "Assistant app voice" setting.

Comment: What is the "Actions Console"? I'm not sure where to find this.

Comment: I guess https://console.actions.google.com/ ist meant here. "console" is the platform for your settings etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is hard to find. Especially if you already have done that setting once.
There is just the check icon. The arrow for "press here to see more settings" is only shown on hover (like in screenshot 1). So it is hidden very well.

1. Go to your **action console** https://console.actions.google.com/
2. Open your action project you want to change voice for.
3. Press "overview" on left top side in menu (screenshot 0).
4. Open **Quick setup** dropdown.
5. Click on "decide how your action is invoked". (Screenshot 1)
6. Find "Google assistant voice" there. (Screenshot 2)

[image][image][image]